# YouTube UITableView from a search query using GData

Tags: iphone, search, youtube, gdata

I'm trying to customize a table view to display a feed of youtube videos based on a search query. I found this code http://pastebin.com/vmV2c0HT which displays a feed of a YouTube channel in a tableview, it works fine. However, when modifying the viewDidLoad function to search for a query instead of a user feed, I always end up with a blank table view.

Here is my viewDidLoad function:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

NSString *searchString = @"football";

NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;

NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForFeedID:nil];

GDataQueryYouTube* query = [GDataQueryYouTube  youTubeQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];

[query setVideoQuery:searchString];

[query setMaxResults:5];

[service fetchFeedWithQuery:query delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(entryListFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:)];

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**--------------------- SOLUTION ----------------------**

The problem was in two parts:

-There was a mistake in the query fetch call, change it to:

[service fetchFeedWithQuery:query delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

the other selector method wasn't implemented

- The service should not follow next links coz then all the feed will be fetched

[_service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:NO];

Comment: I passed by this page http://everburning.com/news/mytube-searching-for-fun-and-profit/ but still no luck, some could find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method look like? Maybe the response you get for a search query is in a different format, and so the previous code you had for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` no longer applies. You can try doing some `NSLog` calls to see what the information looks like if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint m8, I wasn't checking the console.. I solved the problem, it's there in my post.